# Why isn't my code filtering my PivotTable?

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I'm trying to filter multiple PivotTables at one time. The error is occurring on the line beginning with `pt.PivotFields...`, not sure why it's not working:

```
Sub PivotFilter()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim table As String
Dim tablenum As Integer
Dim comptable As String
table = "CD"
Dim Col1 As Integer
Dim Col2 As Integer
Dim Rng1 As Range
Dim Rng2 As Range
Dim Dt1 As Date
Dim Dt2 As Date
Dim pt As PivotTable

For tablenum = 2 To 61
    comptable = table & tablenum
    Col1 = tablenum * 2 + tablenum - 2
    Col2 = tablenum * 2 + tablenum - 1
    Set Rng1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Col1)
    Set Rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Col2)
    Dt1 = Rng1.Value
    Dt2 = Rng2.Value
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(comptable)

    pt.PivotFields("Maturity Date").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=Rng1, Value2:=Rng2

Next tablenum


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: What's the error?  Did you check to see if the value exists before applying the filter?

Answer (score 0):

I have two guesses as to what might be the problem:

1. You have a datatype issue and need to pass the values as actual dates
2. An existing filter is in place, preventing this one from working

This should address either/both:

```
 Dim d1, d2 as Date

 d1 = CDate(Rng1.Value);
 d2 = CDate(Rng2.Value);

 Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(comptable)

 pt.PivotFields("Maturity Date").ClearAllFilters
 pt.PivotFields("Maturity Date").PivotFilters.Add _
     Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=d1, Value2:=d2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Adding PivotFilters**

This error is due to the use of the wrong `Data Type` to pass the parameters to the `PivotFilters.Add2` *Method*.  You are using `Date` instead of `Variant`
*(see [PivotFilters.Add2 Method (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff838592.aspx))*

Below is your original code with some modifications to correct the `Data Type` issue and other minor changes *(commented in the code)*. It’s also suggested to replace `activesheet` with an object variable.

```
Sub PivotFilters_Add2()
Rem Suggest to use a constant instead of a variable
Const kTable As String = "CD"

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim comptable As String
Rem Suggest to use Byte for numbers ranging in value from 0–255.
Dim tablenum As Byte, Col1 As Byte, Col2 As Byte
Dim vDte1 As Variant, vDte2 As Variant

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For tablenum = 2 To 61
        comptable = kTable & tablenum
        Col1 = tablenum * 2 + tablenum - 2
        Col2 = tablenum * 2 + tablenum - 1
        'In this case Ranges are only used to retrieve the values for the filters therefore
        'instead of using ranges just set the value directly into the corresponding variables
        vDte1 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Col1).Value2
        vDte2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, Col2).Value2

        Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(comptable)

        'Suggest to refresh the PivotCache
        'Use this line if all PivotTables share a common PivotCache
        If tablenum = 2 Then pt.PivotCache.Refresh
        'Otherwise use this line instead:   pt.PivotCache.Refresh

        With pt.PivotFields("Maturity Date")
            .ClearAllFilters
            .PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=vDte1, Value2:=vDte2

    End With: Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```